# Ils sont sortis (de / pour) faire une ronde

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> Ils sont sortis **de** faire une ronde.
>
> Ils sont sortis **pour** faire une ronde.
>
> Ils sont sortis faire une ronde.

Antidote dit que *"sortir de" + infinitif* est familier, mais possible ; pourtant, je ne trouve pas cette expression dans des dictionnaires français. Est-ce que la première phrase est correcte ?

Est-ce que la troisième phrase serait possible ?

Comment: une ronde (gardiens)? ou un tour (n'importe qui)? Ils sont sortis **de la situation**. sortir de n'est pas sortir pour faire quelque chose ou sortir faire quelque chose.

Answer (score 2):

Antidote doit faire référence à une phrase du type :

> Je sors de déjeuner.

[Cordial](https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/sortir.php) propose :

> *Je sors de discuter à ce sujet de toi*

Le Larousse :

> *Sortir de déjeuner, de travailler*

Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sortir) :

> Sortir de + inf. Venir de (faire quelque chose). *Il semble qu'en sortant de coucher avec son amant, elle laisse dans sa chambre son sexe comme l'outil de son travail* (Goncourt, *Journal*, 1864, p. 56).

C'est plutôt rare et inadapté dans le cas de ta question car la phrase signifierait qu'ils ont terminé leur ronde, pas qu'ils l'ont commencée.

Tes deux autres phrases sont correctes. Je préfère la dernière, plus directe.

Comment: Merci ! La phrase d'Antidote est _sortir de travailler_ que j'interprète comme _sortir afin de travailler_. J'imagine que je n'ai pas vu l'exemple du TLFI.

Answer (score 1):

La première n'est pas idiomatique. On peut dire des choses comme les suivantes.

- Ils ont **fini** de faire une ronde.
- Ils ont **arrêté** de faire une ronde.
- Ils ont **terminé** de faire une ronde.

La seconde est idiomatique, mais la relation est diffférente ; alors que dans les phrases précédentes la locution prépositionnelle est l'objet du verbe, dans le présent cas c'est le CC de but.

La troisième phrase est aussi idiomatique et a exactement le même sens que la précédente. « Faire une ronde » est un CC de but.

« Sortir de » est idiomatique ; cepedant ça  ne signifie pas « arrêter » ou  « finir », mais  « passer d'un endroit à un autre ».

- (*figurativement*) Ils sont sortis de ce cercle vicieux.  (*Ils sont passé d'une situation qui était un cercle vicieux à une situation qui était saine.*)

Comment: Merci. Ils sont à la maison, puis ils sortent de la maison afin de faire une ronde. // _« Sortir de » est idiomatique ; cepedant ça ne signifie pas « arrêter » ou « finir », mais « passer d'un endroit à un autre »_ --- Oui, c'est ce que je veux dire. Donc ma première phrase est correcte ?

Comment: @Oreste Non, la première phrase n'est pas correcte ; « faire quelque chose » n'est pas un lieu.

Comment: La première phrase est grammaticalement correcte mais pas du tout idiomatique.